# Should I specify h2-h6 sub-headings for a details tag to make the details a distinct section?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have several `<details>` tags that serve as the sections of my page. My understanding is that the `<summary>` tag serves as the heading for `<details>`, so I did not add any `<h2>` headings within or before the `<details>`.

However, to ensure that these `<details>` are indeed separate sections, I am not sure if the details requires sub-headings. My current markup looks something like:

```
<body>
<h1>Page title</h1>

<details>
  <summary>1st Section</summary> <!--should I insert an h2 tag inside the summary to make it a distinct section?-->
  <p> ........... </p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>2nd Section</summary>
  <p> ........... </p>
</details>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<details>` element is a [sectioning root](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interactive-elements.html#the-details-element), so you don't *have* to add a heading. Having said that, feel free to add a heading to its enclosed `<summary>` element, as the `<summary>` element can accept either phrasing content, or one heading element which will serve as the heading for its enclosing `<details>` element.

Comment: Thank you. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines) says sectioning root is not included in the tree/outline. The outline I want is found below. Does including an `h2` within the `summary` tag then make the outline be:
   `1. Page title
   1.1 1st Section
   1.2 2nd Section`

Comment: @JAT86: Sectioning roots don't participate in the main outline. If you want your content to be included in the main outline, use sections, not details. If you need the open/close controls you need to implement those yourself.

Comment: It appears that nesting the `<h2>` tags within the `<summary>` makes the `<details>` a section? I tested it on [HTML 5 Outliner](https://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/) and the `<summary>` text was added in the document outline.

Comment: @JAT86: [That’s an error](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/190/tool-that-displays-outline-of-html5-documents#comment1506_561) in gsnedders’s outliner. You can use one of the other two tools recommended at [Tool that displays outline of HTML5 documents](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/190/60): [hoyois’s outliner](http://hoyois.github.io/html5outliner/) or the [W3C HTML checker](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) (you need to enable the checkbox for "outline" and look at "Structural outline", not "Heading-level outline").

Answer (score 3):

The `details` element is a sectioning root, so it (or its `summary` element) can’t become part of the document outline, whether it includes heading elements or not.

#### Headings outside of `details`

If users could benefit from

- getting an overview which `details` elements the document contains, or
- being able to skip over, or to, certain `details` elements,

it can make sense to provide headings before (groups of) `details` elements.

Nothing special about `details` here, you would do the same if it were a `form`, a few `p` elements, a `ul`, etc.

```html
<body>
<h1>Page title</h1>

<section>
  <h2>foo</h2>
  <details><!-- details 1 --></details>
  <details><!-- details 2 --></details>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>bar</h2>
  <details><!-- details 3 --></details>
</section>

</body>
```

#### Headings within `details`

As the `details` elements is a sectioning root, it gets its own outline. If the content within the `details` element would benefit from the structure (overview, skip), provide heading elements within.

```html
<details>
  <summary><h1>History</h1></summary>
  <p>…</p>

  <section>
    <h2>1800s</h2>
    <p>…</p>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h2>1900s</h2>
    <p>…</p>
  </section>

</details>
```

If you use headings, note that you don’t *have* to place the first heading in the `summary` element, i.e., if you want to use a different label to open/close the `details` than what makes sense for the first heading (in most cases they would be the same, though).